# Calculating MIN and Max Value and Round off to NearValue

Tags: java, math

I am weak in Maths, I need some help regarding the min and max value calculation?

Suppose consider the **MinValue as 200 and MaxValue as 1000**.

Divide both **MinValue and MaxValue by 5** (Here for  me only five values need to display)

Below is the code I have implemented.

```
double initalValue = 200;
        double finalValue = 1000;
        double range = finalValue - initalValue;
        double designCalRange = range/5;
        double intialrange = initalValue;

        System.out.println("designCalRange::>"+designCalRange);


        System.out.println("AtuaValue::>"+Math.ceil(intialrange));
        System.out.println("RoundOffValue::>"+Math.ceil(intialrange/100)*100 + "\n");

        for (double i = 1; i<=5;i++){
            intialrange += designCalRange;
            System.out.println("\n"+"AtuaValue::>"+Math.ceil(intialrange));
            System.out.println("RoundOffValue::>"+Math.ceil(intialrange/100)*100);
        }
    }
```

And My OutPut is 
**

```
RoundOffValue::>200.0
RoundOffValue::>400.0
RoundOffValue::>600.0
RoundOffValue::>700.0
RoundOffValue::>900.0
RoundOffValue::>1000.0
```

**

but it should be :

```
RoundOffValue::>200.0
RoundOffValue::>400.0
RoundOffValue::>600.0
RoundOffValue::>800.0
RoundOffValue::>1000.0
```

Comment: What output does your code give and what output it is supposed to give?

Comment: My minValues is 300 and Max Values is 900 and Following OutPut is designCalRange::>120.0
AtuaValue::>333.0
RoundOffValue::>400.0
AtuaValue::>453.0
RoundOffValue::>500.0
AtuaValue::>573.0
RoundOffValue::>600.0
AtuaValue::>693.0
RoundOffValue::>700.0
AtuaValue::>813.0
RoundOffValue::>900.0
AtuaValue::>933.0
RoundOffValue::>1000.0

Comment: and My outPut Should be Equally divided by 5 and display 5 values

Comment: @Leez Why did you add the C# tag. This is not C#, it already had a language tag.

Comment: I still don't quite understand your requirements. Why don't you just divide every value by 5? Won't that do what you want?

Comment: i am update my question

Comment: I updated the answer, check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting like below

updated to display 5 values

```
   public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int initalValue = 200 ;
        int finalValue = 1000 ;
        int range = finalValue - initalValue;
        int designCalRange = range/4;
        System.out.println("Dividing in to 5 equal intervals");
        System.out.println(initalValue);
        for (double i = 1; i<=3;i++){
            System.out.println((int)(initalValue+designCalRange));
            initalValue = initalValue+ designCalRange;
        }
        System.out.println(finalValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ss also most similar but i need to display on 5 values extactly

Comment: but one more help you out put is designCalRange::>120.0
AtuaValue::>100.0
RoundOffValue::>100.0


AtuaValue::>220.0
RoundOffValue::>300.0

AtuaValue::>340.0
RoundOffValue::>400.0

AtuaValue::>460.0
RoundOffValue::>500.0

AtuaValue::>580.0
RoundOffValue::>600.0

AtuaValue::>700.0
RoundOffValue::>700.0

Comment: In middle 200 is missing

Comment: For the given Input the logic will not print 200, try changing final value to 500 (double finalValue = 500)

Comment: I assumed you need to print 5 number between a given range. And also you want to convert to nearest hundred and print it. is it correct?

Comment: yes, just now i have updated my question please can you through it

Comment: Please give me the input and the expected output

Comment: intial range is 300 and final range is 900. and do you want to divide the difference in to 5 equal interval

Comment: yes or consider my updated question please and display values in 5 equal interval

Comment: and round off to nearest hunderds

Comment: Do you want below output============================================== Dividing in to 5 equal intervals
[300.0 - 420.0]
[420.0 - 540.0]
[540.0 - 660.0]
[660.0 - 780.0]
[780.0 - 900.0]

Comment: I have the code, if you want this output then i'll update the code

Comment: this is not exactly what i need

Comment: In your question Max value is itself 900, How you can expect to display 1000 in output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37179/discussion-between-upog-and-nikhilreddy-gujjula)

Answer (score 0):

This will solve

```
public class DivideBy5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minvalue = 300;
        int maxvalue = 900;
        int increment = (maxvalue - minvalue) / 5;
        int n=minvalue;
        for(int i = 1;i <=5;i++)
        {
            n=n+increment;
            System.out.println(n);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this is not my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need, but it sounds like a problem for the [Paul Heckbert's Nice Numbers algorithm](http://books.google.com/books?id=fvA7zLEFWZgC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Given a min-value, max-value and step-size of an "Axis" the algorithm will calculate the "Prettiest" numbers for the "Axis"

Just imagine it like you have an axis and you wan't to place the ticks at nice round numbers. No matter how big or small the numbers are.

Google resulted in this [Implementation in C#](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/src/3724313.1)

Answer (score 0):

You've got a [fencepost(off-by-one)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error. If you want to display **five** evenly spaced numbers, including the MIN and MAX, then you need to divide the range by `4`, not `5`.

When you divide by 5, you get `160`. You can easily tell this is not the step you want, because it goes like this:

```
 200  ->  200
 360  ->  400
 520  ->  600
 680  ->  700
 840  ->  900
1000  -> 1000
```

When you divide by 4, the step is `200`, which is perfect:

```
 200  ->  200
 400  ->  400
 600  ->  600
 800  ->  800
1000  -> 1000
```